# MacOs: increase maximum of opened files doesn't work for java program

Tags: java, server, configuration, macos-sierra, ulimit

My OS is MacOs sierra, and I increase the maximum of opened files for each process using following commands and make them permanently affected:

```
$ sysctl kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 12288
$ sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=1048600
kern.maxfiles: 12288 -> 1048600
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1048576
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240 -> 1048576
$ ulimit -S -n
256
$ ulimit -S -n 1048576
$ ulimit -S -n
```

**It indeed works when I use `ulimit -a` to see the limit in terminal.**

However, When I run my Java server program, when then socket connection approach 5110,

**"Too many open files Exception is still throw"**

So I write following code to see the parameter of kernel when java running：

```
String [] cmd={"/bin/bash","-c","ulimit -a"};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
InputStream stderr = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
}
```

And the result shows

```
open files                      (-n) 10240
```

It's very confused because I try to increase the limits everywhere I know.

```
* ~/.bash_profile: initialization for login (bash-)shells
* ~/.bashrc: initialization for all interactive (bash-)shells
* ~/.profile
* /etc/bashrc: meant for functions and aliases
* /etc/profile: all types of initialization scripts'
```

Anyone can give me any hints about this question?
Thanks a lot for you.

Comment: What is the real exception being thrown?

Comment: The real exception is:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: Too many open files

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/443168) could be helpful but the question you should ask yourself is why your program needs to have so many files open.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I have already done this operation。 And serveral months ago, these parameters works for my server program written by C.But in java program, they doesn't work.